# Javascript: Searching indexeddb using multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-sql

I want to change from WebSql to Indexeddb. However, how would one do SQL queries like

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ssn = '444-44-4444' and emal = 'bill@bill@company.com'
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ssn = '444-44-4444' and emal = 'bill@bill@company.com' and age = 30
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ssn = '444-44-4444' and emal = 'bill@bill@company.com' and name = 'Bill'
etc
```

with IndexedDB ?
For example, I noticed while reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) of indexedDb, that all the examples only query one index at the time. So you can do

```
var index = objectStore.index("ssn");
index.get("444-44-4444").onsuccess = function(event) {
     alert("Name is " + event.target.result.name);
};
```

But I need to query multiple indexes at the same time!

I also found some interesting posts about [compound indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405650/querying-in-indexeddb), but they only work if you query for all the fields in the compound index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In IndexedDB, is there a way to make a sorted compound query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For your example, compound index still work, but requires two compound indexes

```
 objectStore.createIndex('ssn, email, age', ['ssn', 'email', 'age']); // corrected
 objectStore.createIndex('ssn, email, name', ['ssn', 'email', 'name'])
```

And query like this

```
 keyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(
     ['444-44-4444', 'bill@bill@company.com'],
     ['444-44-4444', 'bill@bill@company.com', '']) 
 objectStore.index('ssn, email, age').get(keyRange)
 objectStore.index('ssn, email, age').get(['444-44-4444', 'bill@bill@company.com', 30])
 objectStore.index('ssn, email, name').get(['444-44-4444', 'bill@bill@company.com', 'Bill'])
```

Indexes can be arranged in any order, but it is most efficient if most specific come first.

Alternatively, you can also use [key joining](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html). Key joining requires four (single) indexes. Four indexes take less storage space and more general. For example, the following query require another compound index

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ssn = '444-44-4444' and name = 'Bill' and age = 30
```

Key joining still work for that query.

Comment: thanks a lot!! However I still can't query using two indexes. I've created a [http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/sDeGz/](jsfiddle) to demonstrate the problem! I also had to change your parameter of objectStore.index into objectStore.index('ssn', 'email', 'age') otherwise I got a "DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8" exception.

Comment: sorry, I have corrected `index` to `createIndex`. no error should issue. but note, IE10 doesn't support compound index.

Comment: ok, thanks. So if I want to search on any combination of fields, I have to create an index for each combination ('ssn', 'ssn, name', 'ssn, email', ssn, name, email', etc) ? How expensive is an index ?, for example, if I have a huge objectStore with 20 indexes ?

Comment: If you need key range query, you have to index. 20 indexes is reasonable. However try to avoid exploding index problem https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Index_Limits

Comment: Also not directly related, it might be worthy to note that when working with variables to make sure you pass the correct type. If in doubt, e.g. use parseInt() or similar.

Comment: This might be the correct link for "key joining", if I'm not mistaken: http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/query/key-joining.html

Comment: @KyawTun I'd love to see a short key joining example for the above example.