# Filter IndexedDB records with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I need to be able to filter some data from an IndexedDB in three different ways.

For example, if the data was stored from the following object:

```
var cars = [
    {type: 'econmoy',colour: 'red',ageRange:'1 - 10'},
    {type: 'econmoy',colour: 'blue',ageRange:'11 - 20'},
    {type: 'luxury',colour: 'yellow',ageRange:'1 - 10'}
]
```

I wanted to allow users to filter the results by type, colour and ageRange separately and/or jointly. I was hoping the ***IDBKeyRange.bound*** method would be the answer but this doesn't work:

```
var lowerArray = ['econmoy','blue','1 - 10'];
var upperArray = ['luxury','yellow','11 - 20'];
var rangeTest = IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerArray,upperArray);
index.openCursor(rangeTest).onsuccess = ...
```

Can anyone suggest a good way of going about it?

Here is a rough fiddle of my initial thoughts: http://jsfiddle.net/As55S/

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: I have solved the issue in a semi dirty way. Will refactor once I have tested - http://jsfiddle.net/q2t3t/2/

Answer (score 2):

Your example seems to works pretty well, unfortunately **AFAIK**, you **cannot** filter multiple properties **separately** on an index array.

The whole indexedDB filter processing rely on the order of the index keys. 
And compound indexe keys must be seen as a simple concatenation of multiple values, so you can search using them, but you need to respect the properties order...

In your example the compound index order is *type*=>*colour*=>*ageRange*...

```
objectStore.createIndex("name", ['type','colour','ageRange'], { unique: false });
```

So you can search on:

- *type*
- *type* **and** *colour*
- *type* **and** *colour* **and** *ageRange*

But you can't filter **separately** *colour* and *ageRange* as you would in a relational database. I personnaly have no good way to do it but here is three possible **ugly** workaround:

- Execute the cursor on the whole Object store, and filter each object in the cursor loop. Easiest to code, and you ll be able to do more complexe filtering (startWith/endWith), but it ll be slower, particulary with an huge amount of rows to browse...

  (**Tips:** You can make this method faster if you force the user to fill at last one specific field bind to an index, to reduce the numbre of rows to be filtered from cursor...)
- Create a compound indexe for every properties order and use the right one depending on your search fields values. It ll result in a large amount codes and indexes for your objectsore, but according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501459/javascript-searching-indexeddb-using-multiple-indexes#comment23714255_16503172), 20 indexes for a single object store is reasonables, so you could support at least 4 search field...

**[EDIT: According to your comment - I may misunderstood]**

- Create a standard index for each properties and use them separately with an [index cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor) to get their primary keys, then merge the results in an array by keeping only the primary keys found in every indexes query. Finally, load one by one the corresponding object from the primary keys merged in the array.

  This way could be pretty good because you don't have to create and
  manage a lot of indexes, and every fields ll support the *startWith*
  filtering. But you loose the straight cursor features, and i wonder
  what would be the performance of loading one by one each record from
  js?

Anyway, I think IndexedDB is not well designed for such usecases. 
If you're planning to do some complex search (multi-criteria queries, statistics...) then relational databases (like WebSQL) are generally more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might try 3 separate indexes and loop through each.