# IndexedDB – search for specific data? How to find the values from another value in a row?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, indexeddb

Below is my example that I have. So far it does the following.

- Enter in 3 values to a row
- Retrieve all the values from all rows on load
- Place all the values from each row and print them to screen that was
  retrieved from the above step.

The part that I need help with is trying to find all the values of one row based on a value that exists in that row.

If a row contains the values name: ‘Andrew’ , phone: ’555-55555’, address: ’123 over there’ I would like to get all the data of that row when some one searches for ‘Andrew’

So far if you look at the function ‘searchItems’ you will see that I am trying to find data based on the value of the search input. The problem I am having is all I can get it to do is alert an “undefined” response.
How can I write the function to have it find things like described above

Also one step further. How can i edit the data that is in the row that was found based on the search input? (I have not written that function yet)

html

```html
<!--jquery-2.1.4.js-->

<body>
  <input type="text" id="dataGoesHere" /> 
   <input type="text" id="moredataGoesHere" />
   <input type="text" id="mostdataGoesHere" />
    <button id="clickme">Save</button>
    <div id="saved"></div>
 
 <br><br>
 
  <input type="text" id="searchString" /> 
    <button id="search">search</button>

</body>
```

js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 myDb = function () {
  var name = "test",
  version = "1",
  db,
  testStoreName = "exampleStore",
  testIndexName = "testIndexName",
  addToTestIndex = false,

  init = function () {
   var deferred = $.Deferred(),
   openRequest = indexedDB.open(name, version);

   openRequest.onupgradeneeded = dbUpgrade;
   openRequest.onsuccess = dbOpen;
   openRequest.onerror = dbError;

   return deferred.promise();

   function dbUpgrade(evt) {
    //here our db is at evt.target.result here we can adjust stores and indexes
    var thisDb = evt.target.result, //the current db we are working with
    newStore = thisDb.createObjectStore(testStoreName, {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
    //Using indexes, you can target specific keys, this can be an array!
    newStore.createIndex("testIndexKey", "testIndexKey", {unique : false});
    console.log("Doing an upgrade");
   }

   function dbOpen(evt) {
    console.log("DB successfully opened");
    db = evt.target.result;
    deferred.resolve();

    getAllItems (function (items) {
     var len = items.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
      console.log(items[i]);
      $('#saved').append('<p>'+items[i].item + ' ' + items[i].george + ' ' + items[i].column3 + ' ' + items[i].id + '</p>');
     }
    });
   }

   function dbError(error) {
    console.log("DB Error");
    console.log(error);
    deferred.reject(error);
   }
  },

  add = function(item, bob, villa) {
   var itemToAdd = {"item" : item, "george" : bob, "column3" : villa},
   objStore,
   request,
   deferred = $.Deferred();
   if (!addToTestIndex) {
    //here we will add half the entries to the index
    //See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501459/javascript-searching-indexeddb-using-multiple-indexes for a better example
    addToTestIndex = !addToTestIndex;
    itemToAdd.testIndexKey = "This is a test";
   }

   //first get the object store with the desired access
   objStore = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readwrite").objectStore(testStoreName);
   //next create the request to add it
   request = objStore.add(itemToAdd);
   request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
   };

   request.onerror = function (evt) {
    deferred.reject(evt);
   };

   return deferred.promise();
  },

  get = function (index) {
   //Since our store uses an int as a primary key, that is what we are getting
   //The cool part is when you start using indexes...
   var deferred = $.Deferred(),
   store = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readonly").objectStore(testStoreName);
   request = store.get(parseInt(index));

   request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
   };

   request.onerror = function (evt) {
    deferred.reject("DBError: could not get " + index + " from " + testStoreName);
   };

   return deferred.promise();
  },
   
  getAllItems = function(callback) {
   var trans = db.transaction(testStoreName, IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
   var store = trans.objectStore(testStoreName);
   var items = [];

   trans.oncomplete = function(evt) {  
    callback(items);
   };

   var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();

   cursorRequest.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
   };

   cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(evt) {                    
    var cursor = evt.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
     items.push(cursor.value);
     cursor.continue();
    }
   };
  },

  searchItems = function(searchString) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred(),
   store = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readonly").objectStore(testStoreName);
   request = store.get(searchString);
   request.onerror = function(event) {
    // Handle errors!
    alert("error");
   };
   
   request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    alert('start seach')
    // Do something with the request.result!)
    alert(event.target.result);
    alert('end search')
   };
  };
   
  return {
   init: init,
   get: get,
   add: add,
   getAllItems: getAllItems,
   searchItems: searchItems
  };
 }

  var db = new myDb();
  db.init().then(function () {
 $("#clickme").click(function(evt) {
  //add, then we will get the added item from the db
  console.log("Adding new item to db");
  
  db.add($('#dataGoesHere').val(), $('#moredataGoesHere').val(), $('#mostdataGoesHere').val())
  
  .then(function (res) {
   return db.get(res);
  })
  
  .then(function (res) {
   $('#saved').append('<p>'+res.item+' '+res.george+' '+res.column3+'</p>');
  });
 });
 
 $("#search").click(function(evt) {
  // search for a specific row
  console.log("searching");

  db.searchItems($('#searchString').val());
 });
 
 
  })


});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing (and could be the probable cause):**  Are you having an index on the key you are trying to search? In you case, for data as `name: ‘Andrew’ , phone: ’555-55555’, address: ’123 over there’` if you trying to search for "Andrew", then you should be having an index created on `"name"`. If it is not there then you will not be able to make a search and that's what probably could be happening.

**Next:** In the data store there could be more than one rows with name as Andrew, so you can have a cursor open using the index and then loop through all value and get the desired one. Something like *(I am just throwing you an idea through this code snippet)*:

```
var objectStoreHandler = transaction.objectStore(selectDataObj.tblName);
var indexHandler = objectStoreHandler.index(selectDataObj.whereColObj.whereColNameArr[0]);
var cursorHandler = indexHandler.openCursor(keyRange);
cursorHandler.onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        console.log("!!!!!");
        if (cursor.value != null && cursor.value != undefined) {
            resultArr.push(cursor.value);
        }
        cursor["continue"]();
    } else {
        console.log("################### " + resultArr);
        return successCallBack(resultArr);
    }
    return;
};
```