# optimizing JSON querying performance in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, query-performance

I have a 10MB JSON file of the following structure (10k entries):

```
{
entry_1: {
    description: "...",
    offset: "...",
    value: "...",
    fields: {
        field_1: {
            offset: "...",
            description: "...",
        },
        field_2: {
            offset: "...",
            description: "...",
        }   
    }
},
entry_2:
...
...
...
```

}

I want to implement an autocomplete input field that will fetch suggestions from this file, as fast as possible while searching multiple attributes. 
For example, finding all entry names,field names and descriptions that contain some substring.

**Method 1:**

I tried to flatten the nesting into an array of strings:

```
"entry_1|descrption|offset|value|field1|offset|description",
"entry_1|descrption|offset|value|field2|offset|description",
"entry2|..."
```

and perform case insensitive partial string match, query took about 900ms.

**Method 2**

I tried Xpath-based JSON querying (using [defiant.js](http://defiantjs.com/)).

```
  var snapshot = Defiant.getSnapshot(DATA);
  found = JSON.search(snapshot, '//*[contains(fields, "substring")]');
```

query took about 600ms (just for a single attribute, `fields`).

Are there other options that will get me to sub 100ms? I have control of the file format so I can turn it into XML or any other format, the only requirement is speed.

Comment: Is it a static json or there is possibility for the json to grow.

Comment: How about filtering the data on server, rather than sending a file of 10MB to each client?

Comment: @priyadarshiswain JSON doesn't change.

Comment: @NisargShah, performance is the top priority. I don't want to fire ajax requests for each letter the user types and then have him wait for a response, I prefer to send 10MB once and have the best performance possible

Comment: @susdu then use a divide and conquer approach. Divide the big file into smaller files based on some search index. if possible have a indexing json which will return the data file json based on search indexing algo. Search indexing algorithm will depend on data.

Comment: What fields are you searching for? I think if this is a write (almost) never and read many you could try indexeddb (natively indexed data in browser).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503172/1641941 Depending on the searches performed you could get a performance improvement when  debouncing keyup (if this is for keyboard and not mobile). Search only when the user stops typing so delay searching for 500ms after the last keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to search for a substring of values it is not a good idea to use indexeddb as suggested. You can try flattening the values of the fields to text where fields seperated by `::` and each key in the object is a line in the text file:

```
{
  key1:{
    one:"one",
    two:"two",
    three:"three"
  },
  key2:{
    one:"one 2",
    two:"two 2",
    three:"three 2"
  }
}
```

Will be:

```
key1::one::two::three
key2::one 2::two 2::three
```

Then use regexp to search for text after the `keyN::` part and store all keys that match. Then map all those keys to the objects. So if `key1` is the only match you'd return [data.key1]

Here is an example with sample data of 10000 keys (search on laptop takes couple of milliseconds but have not tested when throttling to mobile):

```js
//array of words, used as value for data.rowN
const wordArray = ["actions","also","amd","analytics","and","angularjs","another","any","api","apis","application","applications","are","arrays","assertion","asynchronous","authentication","available","babel","beautiful","been","between","both","browser","build","building","but","calls","can","chakra","clean","client","clone","closure","code","coherent","collection","common","compiler","compiles","concept","cordova","could","created","creating","creation","currying","data","dates","definition","design","determined","developed","developers","development","difference","direct","dispatches","distinct","documentations","dynamic","easy","ecmascript","ecosystem","efficient","encapsulates","engine","engineered","engines","errors","eslint","eventually","extend","extension","falcor","fast","feature","featured","fetching","for","format","framework","fully","function","functional","functionality","functions","furthermore","game","glossary","graphics","grunt","hapi","has","having","help","helps","hoisting","host","how","html","http","hybrid","imperative","include","incomplete","individual","interact","interactive","interchange","interface","interpreter","into","its","javascript","jquery","jscs","json","kept","known","language","languages","library","lightweight","like","linked","loads","logic","majority","management","middleware","mobile","modular","module","moment","most","multi","multiple","mvc","native","neutral","new","newer","nightmare","node","not","number","object","objects","only","optimizer","oriented","outside","own","page","paradigm","part","patterns","personalization","plugins","popular","powerful","practical","private","problem","produce","programming","promise","pure","refresh","replace","representing","requests","resolved","resources","retaining","rhino","rich","run","rxjs","services","side","simple","software","specification","specifying","standardized","styles","such","support","supporting","syntax","text","that","the","their","they","toolkit","top","tracking","transformation","type","underlying","universal","until","use","used","user","using","value","vuejs","was","way","web","when","which","while","wide","will","with","within","without","writing","xml","yandex"];
//get random number
const rand = (min,max) =>
  Math.floor(
    (Math.random()*(max-min))+min
  )
;
//return object: {one:"one random word from wordArray",two:"one rand...",three,"one r..."}
const threeMembers = () =>
  ["one","two","three"].reduce(
    (acc,item)=>{
      acc[item] = wordArray[rand(0,wordArray.length)];
      return acc;
    }
    ,{}
  )
;
var i = -1;
data = {};
//create data: {row0:threeMembers(),row1:threeMembers()...row9999:threeMembers()}
while(++i<10000){
  data[`row${i}`] = threeMembers();
}
//convert the data object to string "row0::word::word::word\nrow1::...\nrow9999..."
const dataText = Object.keys(data)
  .map(x=>`${x}::${data[x].one}::${data[x].two}::${data[x].three}`)
  .join("\n")
;
//search for someting (example searching for "script" will match javascript and ecmascript)
//  i in the regexp "igm" means case insensitive
//return array of data[matched key]
window.searchFor = search => {
  const r = new RegExp(`(^[^:]*).*${search}`,"igm")
  ,ret=[];
  var result = r.exec(dataText);
  while(result !== null){
    ret.push(result[1]);
    result = r.exec(dataText);
  }
  return ret.map(x=>data[x]);
};
//example search for "script"
console.log(searchFor("script"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I went for a similar idea