# IndexedDB with range queries

Tags: date, range, indexeddb

I would like to find which date ranges overlaps another date range in IndexedDB.

Something like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE (periodStart >= start AND periodStart < end)
OR (start >= periodStart AND start <= periodEnd)
```

Events looks like the following object:

```
[{
  title: 'foo',
  start: 'Tue Oct 29 2013 10:19:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)',
  end: 'Tue Oct 29 2013 13:19:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
},
{
  title: 'bar',
  start: 'Tue Oct 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)',
  end: 'Tue Oct 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying in IndexedDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405650/querying-in-indexeddb)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no ability to do unions in indexeddb (the OR).

So, as that kinda sucks, here is a half thought out solution that maybe puts you on the course: something like find the min of the set, and the max of the set, and then a query descending and a query ascending but just get the first record from each cursor, and then, something.