# Query in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I use 'IndexedDB' in Mobile Web.
I want to query.
    a >= 10 and a <= 20 and b >= 30 and b <= 40
I tried like below.
    //Create complex index.
    var store = thisDB.createObjectStore("table", {autoIncrement:true}); 
    store.createIndex("myidx",["a","b"],{unique:false}); 
    //Query by bound
    var range = IDBKeyRange.bound([10, 30],[20, 40]); 
    cursor = index.openCursor(range);
    cursor.onsuccess = function(e) { 
        var res = e.target.result; 
        if (res.key[1] >= 30 && res.key[1] <= 40) {
            console.log(res.value);
        }; 
        res.continue(); 
    };

Is this the best? 
I want to get at a time without compare again. 
Even more, Slow speed. 
The data is 1,000 of about 100,000. 
It takes about 10 seconds or more. 
Too slow. 
Any suggestions? 
How is the WebSQL?
I worry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying in IndexedDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405650/querying-in-indexeddb)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two range queries. Sorted merge key joining is not possible for this case. It will be slow on WebSQL too.

Since both variables are numbers, you can use geohash to get fast query.

Another ways is keeping both query results into sorted arrays of primary keys. The result is simply look up intersection on both results.